# Package uses conflict: Import-Package: de.foo.bar; version="0.0.0"

Tags: java, osgi

I try to install a bundle in an OSGi environment (FUSE ESB) but do not manage to get it resolved. The error message is:

```
The bundle could not be resolved. Reason: Package uses conflict: Import-Package: de.foo.bar; version="0.0.0"
```

My bundle imports the package *de.foo.bar*.
The bundle which exports the package *de.foo.bar* does this with a 'uses' directive.

```
Export-Package = de.foo.bar;uses:="{other packages}";version="2.4.0"
```

As I understood I have to ensure that my bundle must import all other packages mentioned in the 'uses' directive of the de.foo.bar package (in the right version).

I checked this and also tried several version changes (0.0.0 and the real version numbers) but can not get it to work.

So, what does the error message realy means (maybe I understood it wrong)? What do I have to check?

Thanks for any help

Klaus

---

*System Information:*

- [FUSE ESB 4.2.0](http://fusesource.com/products/enterprise-servicemix4/) (based on servicemix)
- using [maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html) 2.1.0 to generate OSGi MANIFEST header

Comment: Does it work if you just remove the `uses` and `version` attributes from the `Export-packages` declaration? As far as I remember, they're optional.

Comment: The attributs are added by the maven-bundle-plugin (even if I specify the bundle by name and not by wildcard) and I do not know how to avoid this. Nevertheless I think it might be worth to understand the message and configure things correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found what was wrong.

My bundle is a Spring Dynamic Module bundle and I did a mistake in the spring bean configuration (use a 'ref' instead a 'value' in a constructor-arg). Normally spring configuration errors are reported as such - I do not know why the current error resulted in the misleading message.

EDIT:

The faulty Spring configuration does not cause the *uses conflict*. It finally was the import of the package *org.apache.log4j* which is exported by different bundles (in my FUSE ESB container) and apparently was different wired to the bundles I tried to install.

Trying to solve my problem I found the article [Diagnosing OSGi uses conflicts](http://blog.springsource.com/2008/11/22/diagnosing-osgi-uses-conflicts/) which I found helpfull to understand the problem.