# Package uses conflict: Import-Package with jasperreports

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, equinox

I have the common "use conflict" problem in OSGi, I am new to OSGi so sorry if this is very simple. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504113/package-uses-conflict-import-package-on-startup-of-a-bundle) and [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466379/package-uses-conflict-import-package-de-foo-bar-version-0-0-0) questions. I have also read [this](http://blog.springsource.org/2008/11/22/diagnosing-osgi-uses-conflicts/) which explains in more detail how to debug these problems; yet, i can't figure it out. I can't find the duplicated export (quoting that last article "There must always be more than one supplier for you to see a uses constraint violation.")

This is the full error

```
initial@reference:file:../../Dev/mine/target/dependency/jasperreports-3.7.1-osgi.jar [151]
  Package uses conflict: Import-Package: org.apache.commons.collections.comparators; version="0.0.0"
```

Here is the relevant snippet of the jasper manifest. It is too long to paste completely

```
Export-Package: ...,net.sf.jasperreports.crosstabs.fill.calculation;uses:="org.apache.commons.collections,net.sf.jasperreports.engine,org.apache.commons.collections.comparators,org.apache.commons.logging,..."
```

And here is the output of `packages org.apache.commons.collections.comparators` to show that the package is exported correctly and only once

```
osgi> packages org.apache.commons.collections.comparators
org.apache.commons.collections.comparators; version="3.2.0"<org.apache.commons.collections_3.2.0 [869]>
```

Any ideas? something else i could try? I really doubt this but, is equinox complaining that the exported version is 3.2.0 but the `uses` version is 0.0.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with a third option. It's related to @PeterKriens suggestion, hopefully it will be another approach for others to tackle these problems.
I installed [Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/), which runs on top of Felix and used the hot-deploy folder to deploy **one jar at a time**. This way I could see the problems as they arose. It is very slow but verbose. Using only Felix I found no way to deploy like this

Answer (score 2):

Try running this on Apache Felix. It provides an extensive trace when it discovers a uses conflict.

Answer (score 0):

try read my other (long) answer at [Package uses conflict: Import-Package on startup of a bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504113/package-uses-conflict-import-package-on-startup-of-a-bundle/13301599#13301599)
I put there a fairly detailed how-to find the conflict.